# MDBDataTable Cannot Sort Column if Cell Contains HTML

Tags: html, reactjs, datatables, jsx, mdbreact

I'm trying to generate a sortable and searchable table in reactjs using `mdbreact` like so

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBDataTable } from 'mdbreact';

const tableData = {
    columns: [
        {
            field: 'first_name',
            label: 'First Name'
        },
        {
            field: 'last_name',
            label: 'Last Name'
        },
        {
            field: 'age',
            label: 'Age'
        }
    ],
    rows: [
        {
            first_name: <a href='/example-route/John'>John</a>,
            last_name: 'Smith',
            age: 29
        },
        {
            first_name: <a href='/example-route/Jane'>Jane</a>,
            last_name: 'Doe',
            age: 34
        }
    ]
};

class Table extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <MDBDataTable data={tableData} />
        )
    }
}

export default Table;
```

The table renders just fine, but because there are `<a></a>` tags in the body, the relevant column becomes **unsortable** and **unsearchable**.

I've thought for a few days now about how to make that column sortable and searchable, but after doing a boatload of reading I've come up blank.

**UPDATE**

It seems that in Chrome the column is neither searchable nor sortable, but in Firefox the column is sortable but not searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ref: https://mdbootstrap.com/support/react/make-a-mdbdatatable-row-clickable/

I have found a reserved row key called `clickEvent` that can be used like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBDataTable } from 'mdbreact';

class Table extends React.Component {

    handleClick(name) {
        console.log(name);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <MDBDataTable data={{
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: 'first_name',
                        label: 'First Name'
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'last_name',
                        label: 'Last Name'
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'age',
                        label: 'Age'
                    }
                ],
                rows: [
                    {
                        first_name: 'John',
                        last_name: 'Smith',
                        age: 29,
                        clickEvent: () => this.handleClick('john')
                    },
                    {
                        first_name: 'Jane',
                        last_name: 'Doe',
                        age: 34,
                        clickEvent: () => this.handleClick('jane')
                    }
                ]
            }} />
        )
    }
}

export default Table;
```

I can then handle the click event in whichever way I'd like, maybe using `window.location.href = '/' + name;` to simulate the required functionality of an `<a>` tag.